# SQL Reporting Services Permission Management by Using Active Directory

Tags: reporting-services

Is it possible to manage report permissions by using Active Directory? For example, I have an employee performance report. Employee can open the report by choosing his/her name from the dropdown parameter. This parameter dropdown lists the all employee names. However, most of the employees must see just their names in that dropdown. It must be forbidden to see other employees names. Moreover, the department heads must see the all employee list in that dropdown. How can I make a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is by using the built-in User!UserID field, which returns the credentials of the person running the report.  If your users are accessing SSRS using their Windows domain credentials, then User!UserID will return as string that looks like DOMAIN\userid.  As long as you have somewhere in the database where you can link the user's Windows login to their name, then you can use that to restrict the dataset that returns the parameter dropdown (either as a SQL parameter or as an SSRS dataset filter).